# How do I implement video streaming functionality in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-live-streaming, ipfs, hls.js

I'm creating a Web application using (React.js+Node.js).

The application looks like Youtube. In the application, I want video streaming functionality the same as Youtube. For the file storage. I'm using (IPFS) Interplanetary File System. How can I create this functionality? Any suggestions or resources?

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to google it. Just googling "node video streaming"  has 17M results

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a community library like [react-player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player). It has all the functionality you should need to display and start/stop a video. There are others worth checking out too, but the react-player interface is pretty straightforward in my opinion.